# Binary data with prisma via API call

Tags: prisma

I can fetch data via my api just fine, but i am not sure how to properly get the binary column data from my postgresql database. When i run it through imsomnia it gives an object with a `buffer` and `data` attribute. Should I be casting it somehow with prisma?

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could provide further context. In particular, what your schema looks like, the API endpoint, and what data you are seeing (and what you want).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.